# Appending app version name to app name

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to identify different versions of development builds released. Is it possible to append app's **version name** to app name or display **version name** as **App name** for development builds, so that I can identify the version from launcher itself.

Is there any better approach for doing this?

Comment: why not use a small textview somewhere that shows app version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to append app's versionname to app name or display
>   versionname as appname for development builds ?

Yes. What you can do is in  **build.gradle** declare   `def versionName = "1.0"`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    def versionName = "1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName versionName
    }


    productFlavors {
        flavor1{
            resValue "string", "app_name", "YourAppName"+versionName
        }


    }
}
```

**Note :** remove **app_name** from `string.xml` or it will through exception of duplicate resource.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game, but found a way to keep the app name in *strings.xml* to have it nicely localisable for release builds while being able to add a suffix for debug builds.

Similar to N J's answer define a variable for the version name, then use `manifestPlaceholders` to spice up the app name defined in manifest.

In *strings.xml*:

```
<string name="app_name">My app</string>
```

In *build.gradle*:

```
def versionName = '1.0'

android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      versionName versionName
      manifestPlaceholders.appName = "@string/app_name"
   }

   buildTypes {
      debug {
         ...
         manifestPlaceholders.appName = "My app $versionName"
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Then in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<application
   ...
   android:label="${appName}"
   ...
```

**If you have flavors and need flavor AND build type information in your app name** you cannot set the placeholder in `buildTypes.debug`, but instead you need to resort to the variants API. This may look like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    final buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name
    final flavorName = variant.flavorName
    switch (buildTypeName) {
        // release name is set via defaultConfig, but could also be set here
        case 'debug':
            variant.mergedFlavor.manifestPlaceholders.appName = "MyApp $versionName $flavorName $buildTypeName"
            break
    }
}
```